# Symfony 2 - configuration to Command Container

Tags: php, symfony, command

I have defined in app/config.yml sample:

```
module_my_module
   key: value1
   key2: value2
```

And a bundle with DependecyInjection Configuration.php:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Bundle\MyModuleBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('module_configuration');
        $rootNode->children()
                ->scalarNode('key')->defaultValue('')->end()
                ->scalarNode('key2')->defaultValue('')->end()
            ->end()
            ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

A problem is how to call config.Bundle/Command class:

```
namespace Modules\Bundle\MyBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

//use \Modules\Bundle\NodeSocketBundle\DependencyInjection as DependencyInjection;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
    $this->getParams("key.val"); // GEt a key from config.yml
    }

}
```

Config.yml:

```
module_configuration
     key:  val
```

Comment: In a `ContainerAwareCommand ` you can access to params as  `$this->getContainer()->getParameter("param_name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inject your params in the Container in the `Extension` Bundle Class definition.

In your case you must have something similar to:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Bundle\MyModuleBundle\DependencyInjection;


class MyModuleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('...');

        $container->setParameter('my_first_key', $config['key']);
        $container->setParameter('my_second_key', $config['key2']);

    }
}
```

Then you can access to the value, in your `Command`class as:

```
class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
    $this->getContainer()->getParameter("my_first_key");
    }

}
```

Hope this help